# Como cargar datos en fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ts

Estoy intentando hacer uso de la librería **fullcalendar** para mostrar datos en un calendario desde base de datos, sin embargo no sé como realizar esta acción, tengo una variable llamada 'items' la cual obtiene la información de los eventos desde la base datos, sin embargo al intentar mostrarlo desde fullcalendar, este genera un error, este es el código que estoy intentando realizar:

```
    this.calendarOptions = {
      plugins:[ dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin],
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
                headerToolbar: {
                    left: 'prev,next',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay',
                },
                editable: false,
                events: this.items,
                locale: 'es',                  
      }
```

la variable `this.items` obtiene la siguiente información:

```
allDay: false
backgroundColor: "red"
borderColor: "red"
display: "list-item"
resourceId: 25
start: "2023/06/16"
title: "Prueba creacion"
```

y el error que me retorna desde la consola de chrome es el siguiente:

> Error: viewType "" is not available. Please make sure you've loaded all neccessary plugins